# Drag and Drop Modules Views in regions Prism Unity 6.1.0

Tags: c#, wpf, module, drag-and-drop, prism

I am using Prism 6.1.0 with Unity, and Prism MVVM.

I want to be able to drag and drop the view of my prism modules from one region to another (Like the windows in Visual studio).

I can't manage to find a tutorial or some guides.
Is it possible to do such thing ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution.

I will use prism with AvalonDock. Looks like they can work fine together and AvalonDock does everything i need to do great drag and drop on docks.